# RibbonMenuButton in WPF / XAML bigger then 32*32

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I try to create a RibbonMenuButton that is bigger than the default 32*32 Pixel in WPF 4.5.

I tried something like this:

```
<RibbonMenuButton Margin="-50 -30 0 0" Width="40" Height="40"             
VerticalContentAlignment="Top" LargeImageSource="{StaticResource MyButtonSource}">
```

But obviously that does not work.
How can I achieve my goal of having for example a 40*40 RibbonMenuButton?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the documentation in MSDN says, you cannot have icons larger than 32x32.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc872782.aspx